# virtualbox importing appliance fails

Tags: virtualbox, 64-bit, appliance

I installed Ubuntu 64 bit on my laptop (2Gb RAM) and exported to an appliance.  We copied the ova file to another machine (I7, 16Gb RAM, Window7 64 bit).  The target machine is an HP Elitebook 9470M Ultrabook

The virtualbox is 5.02R on both sides.

Importing works without complaint, but when run, the vm will not load with the error message:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine sitdev
A new node couldn't be inserted because one with the same name exists
```

Not sure if this is relevant, but having given up momentarily, we tried loading Ubuntu-64 and installing a new virtual machine from scratch. The only choices were 32 bit.  Nothing 64.

Could this be some BIOS setting?  Clearly the cpu can support 64 bit OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14462) submitted to VirtualBox. The reason for the error is that a line defining the OHCI controller gets duplicated, hence the "same name exists" error message. There is a workaround mentioned on the page.

> You can work around this bug by extracting the ova file, removing the duplicate OHCI line, and re-creating the ova file using tar. It's not possible to remove the extra OHCI using the GUI.

Comment: I will try the fix, but what about being unable to create a new 64bit unix vm?

Comment: Either VT-X is disabled in BIOS or some other application is already using it. Close all other applications and try again, and check your BIOS settings.

Comment: The other workaround mentioned in the bug report thread, to simply disable and then re-enable USB in the Settings GUI, also works and requires no OVA hackery.